# Lenovo N500 Won't Start

Tags: boot, lenovo-laptop

I broke my laptop by banging its keyboard. It now won't start and only shows a black screen. It shows the LED lights that it's connected to the battery adapter and that it's turned on, but won't do anything else. I removed the hard drive and it tested OK in another laptop.

Comment: If its still under warranty I'd send it in. Opening it up can void your warranty depending on the vendor.

Comment: +1 for admitting to "banging its keyboard" and breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any beeps when you turn it on?  Does an external monitor show anything when connected?

If answers to both of those is no, you probably have a dead mainboard. Very unlikely to be worthwhile to try and fix.